# C2260 undeclared identifier

Tags: visual-c++

I am getting the error amOrPm undeclared identifier any help? I have tried lots of things and im sure it is something simple.

boy it sure asks me for a lot of details i hope i am explaining it clear enough for everyone.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

// Declare constants
void input(int&hrs, int&mins, int&amOrPm);
int covert(int hrs, int amOrPm);
void outputStime(int hrs, int mins,int amOrPm);
void outputMtime(int hrs, int mins);

 int main()
{
// Declare variables below here
int hrs = 0, mins = 0, amOrPm = 0;
char choice;

cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed | ios::showpoint);

do 
{
    input (hrs, mins, amOrPm);
    covert(hrs, amOrpm);
    outputStime (hrs, mins, amOrPm);
    outputMtime (hrs,mins);

} while (choice != 'q' && choice != 'Q');

return 0;
}

void input(int&hrs, int&mins, int&amOrPm)
{
cout << "Enter The Hour: ";
cin >> hrs;

cout << "Enter The Minutes: ";
cin >> mins;

cout << "Enter 1 AM or 2 for PM: ";
cin >> amOrPm;

}

int convert(int hrs, int amOrPm)
{

    while (amOrPm = 2)
    {
        if (hrs >= 1)
        {
            hrs = hrs + 12;
            return hrs;
        }
        else
        {
            return hrs;
        }
    }
    while (amOrPm = 1)
    {
        if (hrs <= 11)
        {
            return hrs;
        }
        else
        {
            hrs = hrs - 12;

            return hrs;
        }
    }
}

 void outputStime(int hrs, int mins, int amOrPm)
{
    cout << " Standard time is: " << hrs << ":" << mins << amOrPm <<    endl;
}

void outputMtime(int hrs, int mins, int amOrPm)
{
    cout << " Standard time is: " << hrs << ":" << mins << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
covert(hrs, amOrpm);
```

should be

```
convert(hrs, amOrPm);
```

Also,

```
while (amOrPm = 2)
```

and

```
while (amOrPm = 1)
```

should be

```
while (amOrPm == 2)
while (amOrPm == 1)
```

One equal sign means assignment, you are setting amOrPm to 2 or 1. Two equal signs (==) is a comparison, you are comparing amOrPm to 2 or 1.

And

```
int covert(int hrs, int amOrPm);
```

should be

```
int convert(int hrs, int amOrPm);
```

in order to match the function implementation at the end of the program.

Comment: Thanks I made those changes cause you are correct but however it still says the same thing :(

Comment: Did you change amOrpm to amOrPm?

Comment: I just did an now it changed the error to

1 unresolved externals Error LNK1120 COSC 1010

unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl outputMtime(int,int)" (?outputMtime@@YAXHH@Z) referenced in function _main Error LNK2019 COSC 1010

Comment: Fixed that error now i have to figure out why it wont convert and display the military time

Comment: Your outputMtime function has: cout << " Standard time is: " << hrs << ":" << mins << endl; but you might want to change it so that it says " Military time is: "